# Is there any way to disable hover action on particularly some nodes in networkchart of highcharts based on the node color.?

Tags: svg, highcharts

Is there any way to disable hover action on particularly some nodes in networkchart of highcharts based on the node color.?

We implemented search for nodes of network graph and made the nodes which are not matched to gray color. Now we need to disable the hover effect to the nodes which are in gray color. Any Inputs are Welcome

https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-formbuilder-in-reactive-forms/

https://www.positronx.io/angular-httpclient-http-service/

https://codesandbox.io/embed/xenodochial-ritchie-0eu045?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

https://codesandbox.io/embed/intelligent-currying-epg88v?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```html
 @Input() data: any;
  previousData: any;

  ngDoCheck() {
    if (this.data !== this.previousData) {
      this.previousData = this.data;
      console.log('Data has changed:', this.data);
      // Perform any necessary actions here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the below small plugin to prevent all hover effects on a point depending on a color.

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Point.prototype, 'onMouseOver', function(proceed) {
        if (this.color !== 'red') {
            proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        }
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1h83ek4u/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation. Iam getting this error while implementing the above logic @ppotaczek

Comment: You didn't mention that you are using typescript. Anyway, you need to add types, please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n4zubmpq/

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. saved us a lot of time. Kudos